# How to analyse the big data in real time?

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata

I need to perform full text search against elasticsearch and then i want to perform some computational heavy analysis on that data and send the result back to the client. what is the best approach would be, i'm new to this.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. Elasticsearch can do aggregations and filtering via its API. What more are you trying to do?

Comment: i need to perform very heavy computational analysis over huge data but i'm not sure elasticsearch aggregation is enough for that.

Comment: That's still very vague. Please give an example... My suggestion would be to look at using Apache Spark's Elasticsearch support

Comment: example: i run full text-search query against elasticsearch that  returns result of total 30k matching documents. so now i want all 30k documents to do calculation and produce final result i want.

Comment: thanks, yes i'm also thinking about apache spark but i'm new to this so i don't know  how to approach this in really efficient way.

Comment: my flow:  userquery => elastisearch => calulation => result

Comment: Again, "a calculation".... **what calculation**? Please do some research into Spark, try reading from Elasticsearch using it, [then ask a specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks cricket for your suggestion.